# How to change properties file and refresh configuration class on run time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have `properties` file on `classpath` and `configuration class` in `java` which maps this properties file. When I am changing my properties file I want to refresh `configuration` `class` too  to take new value and I want to do it without restart `server`, is there any solution how can I do it ? I am using `spring mvc`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `@RefreshScope`

Doc:

> A Spring @Bean that is marked as @RefreshScope will get special
>   treatment when there is a configuration change. This addresses the
>   problem of stateful beans that only get their configuration injected
>   when they are initialized. For instance if a DataSource has open
>   connections when the database URL is changed via the Environment, we
>   probably want the holders of those connections to be able to complete
>   what they are doing. Then the next time someone borrows a connection
>   from the pool he gets one with the new URL.
>
> The RefreshScope is a bean in the context and it has a public method
>   refreshAll() to refresh all beans in the scope by clearing the target
>   cache. There is also a refresh(String) method to refresh an individual
>   bean by name. This functionality is exposed in the /refresh endpoint
>   (over HTTP or JMX).

And use like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:configprops.properties")
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigProperties {
    // previous code
}
```

Comment: I jave `@Configuration` `class` like this   `@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:scheduler.properties")
@RefreshScope
public class AzryConfig {

    @Value("${fixedDelay.in.milliseconds}")
    private String azryFixed;

    @Value("${initial.in.milliseconds}")
    private String azryInitial; // other getter setters` and when i am injecting this class it can not read, when i removed `@RefreshScope` it worked succesees(read properties)